# Not calculating in less

Tags: css, less

In less I'm using CSS math to render elipse

```
border-radius: 0 0 120px 120px / 0 0 12px 12px;
```

But less is calculating this. How to prevent it from doing it?

Comment: Can you explain the problem in more detail ? How about posting a fiddle too . Codepen lets you add Less directly. I think JSFiddle only allows Sass at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LESS, you can let the compiler [know something should be handled like a string](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e)

```
border-radius: ~"0 0 120px 120px / 0 0 12px 12px";
```